# Multi Level Grouping in ExtJS 4.X grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-grid

I am looking for multilevel grouping feature in ExtJs 4.1 grid which is not supported out of the box

I have gone through so many links but I don't think there is a right answer when it comes to multi level grouping in ExtJs 4.X

1. [Link 1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226739)
2. [Link 2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242633)
3. [Link 3](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150858)
4. [Link 4](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?42454-Multiple-level-of-grouping-in-grids/page30)
5. [Link 5](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?42454-Multiple-level-of-grouping-in-grids&p=358156#post358156)

I have also created [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1t5) which tries to mock one the example but its not working.

Please share an example of multilevel grouping in ExtJS 4.X grid.

Thanks !!!